# sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() was working with @Transactional but sessionFactory.openSession() was not

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

The below code was not working. The issue was transaction was not getting committed in db

Case 1 :

```
            @Transactional
            public void save(Person p) {
                Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
                session.saveOrUpdate(p);
                session.close();
            }
```

but when I used below code then it was working fine :

Case 2:

```
            @Transactional
            public void save(Person p) {
                this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(p);
            }
```

Queries :

1. For Case 1 issue I was searching on google like @Transactional not working. But when I used Case 2 by mistake then it started working. Why?
2. After using Case 2 solution, when I added below line in hibernate properties

   **hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread**

It started giving me the error, then the transaction is not active.

What's actual error?

Comment: session.flush(); was not written

Answer (score 1):

1. When you make your call to `session.saveOrUpdate(p);` 
   you tell Hibernate to update or add the entity.
   However, the corresponding record will still not exist in the underlying database.

You need to make the call to [session.flush()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush()) in order to sync the database with the Hibernate session.

Note that if your program were to end without your calling `session.flush()` then that record will not be updated.

2. When you Configured with 'thread'

> hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread

Hibernate will bind the Session returned from `getCurrentSession()` to the current thread and you must manage transactions programmatically.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
...
//code here
...
session.getTransactionCommit();
```